# Switch off request validation in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

is it possible to switch request validation in the view.
I would like to switch it off in the view because of this bit of code in the base controller

```
protected override void Execute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (!this.CurrentStore.IsDefault)
        {
            IStoreRepository storeRepo = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IStoreRepository>();
            IStoreEntity store = storeRepo.GetById(this.CurrentStore.Id);
            this.CurrentStore = store;
        }

        base.Execute(requestContext);
    }
```

it fails in `base.Execute(requestContext);`

N.B I do not wish to switch it off for my entire site. I would like to switch it off in a few action methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC you don't do it at the view level, you do it at the *controller* or a *method of the controller* level. You can use ValidateInput attribute for that, for example:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [ValidateInput(false)] // prevent validation on this method
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```